# Music don't start on button click

Tags: java, android

When I go to install the app on the device, I click the button but nothing happen.
I want to make device play `tosse.acc` from res/raw when I click the button...

Ok resolved the problem :) thanks for answers guys :D ( i have changed the name of the song from tosse to toxxe)

```
 public void  tosse1(View v)  {
Button one = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.toxxe);
one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Resume the music player

        mp.start();
    }
});


}
```

Here my code:

```
    public void  tosse1(View v) {
    Button one = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.create(this, R.raw.tosse);
    one.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
                // Resume the music player

            mp.start();
        }
    });


}
```

`activity_main`:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.tosseapp.app.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:onClick="tosse1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

`AndroidManifest`:

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.tosseapp.app.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You have to ready the music before it can play.

Comment: read the doc. `create` is a static function that creates and return a MediaPlayer.

Comment: please post also the logcat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your `mp` as private variable in your class:

```
  public class PlayaudioActivity extends Activity {

    private MediaPlayer mp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        stopPlaying();
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(PlayaudioActivity.this, R.raw.tosse);
        mp.start();
        }

    });


    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend you to create the MediaPlayer instandce outside of the onClick inner class, because in that way it will create a new instance everytime the button is clicked :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try getting a Mediaplayer Instance like this:

```
 final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.tosse);
```

should solve your problem, because it also prepares the MediaPlayer, see [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#create%28android.content.Context,%20android.net.Uri%29):

> public static MediaPlayer create (Context context, int resid) Added in API level 1
>   Convenience method to create a MediaPlayer for a given
>   resource id. On success, prepare() will already have been called and
>   must not be called again.
>
> When done with the MediaPlayer, you should call release(), to free the
>   resources. If not released, too many MediaPlayer instances will result
>   in an exception.